# How to let user only rearrange layers in a group layer?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, development

We have a stand-alone application were we let the users add local shape and raster layers. We would like to add functionality so that the user can rearrange the added layers within a specific group layer.

We know it's possible to [enable drag and drop](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Enable_layer_drag_and_drop_in_the_TOCControl/00010000039t000000/) on the TocControl but it lets the user rearrange all layers and that's not an option for us. Is there a way to enable drag and drop only on a specific group layer or somehow mimic the same behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not as visually cool but at least it work, use the [MoveLayerEx](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/MoveLayerEx_Method/00120000090n000000/) in [IMapLayers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IMapLayers_Interface/0012000008zs000000/) can be used to move a layer in a group layer, use the same grouplayer as source and target and apply the index that the layer shall have in the group. Made a small code sample:

```
Private Sub MoveGroupLayerItem(ByVal up As Boolean)
        Dim layer As ILayer = getLayer()
        Dim layerIndex As Integer = getLayerGroupIndex()

        Dim map As IMap = axMapControl1.ActiveView.FocusMap

        Dim mapLayers As IMapLayers = CType(map, IMapLayers)

        Dim groupLayer As IGroupLayer = CType(map.Layer(0), IGroupLayer)
        Dim compLayer As ICompositeLayer = CType(groupLayer, ICompositeLayer)


        If up Then
            If layerIndex > 0 Then
                mapLayers.MoveLayerEx(groupLayer, groupLayer, layer, layerIndex - 1)
            End If
        Else
            If (layerIndex < compLayer.Count - 1) Then
                mapLayers.MoveLayerEx(groupLayer, groupLayer, layer, layerIndex + 1)
            End If
        End If

        axMapControl1.Refresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewAll, Nothing, Nothing)
    End Sub
```