# How to group layers in ArcEngine 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine

I was wondering if there is a way I can code the TOC control so that I can select multiple layers and **GROUP** them together. So if i uncheck the group, all layers will be unchecked and be invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to do some coding, because I haven't seen anything similar to the ArcMap [Group](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000011000000.htm) context menuitem in engine.

But you should be able to do this with a group layer.

One way would be to create a [group layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GroupLayerClass_Class/0012000000vz000000/) and [add](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Add_Method/0012000005z2000000/) the layers in the group layer instead of the map and add the group layer to the [map](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/AddLayer_Method/001200000m8m000000/). Don't forget to fire the [ContentsChanged()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ContentsChanged_Method/0012000001ms000000/) on the Active View otherwise the Toc will not be refreshed and [PartialRefresh(esriViewAll,Nothing,Nothing)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/PartialRefresh_Method/0012000001nm000000/) to update the map.

An other way would be to move the layers to the newly created group layer, see the question [rearrange layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2596/how-to-let-user-only-rearrange-layers-in-a-group-layer). To find out the layers that get clicked you need to use the [HitTest](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/HitTest_Method/00160000036w000000/), check out the [context menu](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Displaying_a_TOCControl_context_menu/0001000000s5000000/) sample on how to use hit testing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that group layer a try, i notice there is a "Group Layer" class in Engine too, but i didn't try because I can't get Engine 10 to support Multiple Selection in TOC, I don't think its supported, but i'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ArcObjects example of how to turn on and off a group layer via the TOC ("pGroupLayer.Visible = True
").

```
        pMap = m_Mxdoc.FocusMap

        Dim pContentsView As IContentsView
        pContentsView = m_Mxdoc.CurrentContentsView

        For i = 0 To pMap.LayerCount - 1
            If pMap.Layer(i).Name = "My Layer" Then
                pLayer = pMap.Layer(i)
                If TypeOf pLayer Is IGroupLayer Then
                    pGroupLayer = pLayer
                    pContentsView.SelectedItem = pLayer
                    pGroupLayer.Visible = True

                    m_Mxdoc.UpdateContents()
                    m_Mxdoc.ActiveView.Refresh()

                End If
            End If
        Next i
```