# Selecting Multiple Layers under Table of Contents

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine

I have been trying out what ARCMap10 can do in terms of the TOC. And their TOC has a lot of good functionalities.

I really want to figure out how to Group/Drag and Drop/ and select multiple layers.

As for this question, do you guys know how to select multiple layer in the TOC?
This is for ArcEngine 10 .Net

Comment: Hi Kev84, Welcome to GIS.se :)  Isn't this really the same question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7746/how-to-group-layers-in-arcengine-10#question ? Instead of posting a new almost-the-same question you can edit your existing question, or add clarification in the comments to it.

Comment: Actually the main point of the other question was to ask about grouping, and i have been told to not ask more then 1 question per thread. So I split it up. Regards

Comment: If you really need this, perhaps you could skip the control altogether and program your own as a WPF TreeView Control.

Comment: in that case the questions could benefit from some further details as to what makes them distinct from each other. That isn't clear to me, though now that the answers are more fully developed it's starting to resolve. Nor was it clear to the person who flagged the post for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad news, you can't select multiple layers in the TOC, but there is an ideas that you can vote for here: http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=0873000000089hK

Comment: Yea i know it is not supported for 9.3, was hoping there is a chance it'll work for 10, is that ideas.arcgis.com page stating not possible for 10? I hate how esri limits on the functionality for Engine. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, got to it from resources.arcgis.com, and I also tried in ArcGIS Engine 10 and it didn't work. I fully understand the frustration.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS you can hold down the Shift key to select layers consecutively, and Control to select specific layers.

Comment: I just checked, and this works for all Table of Contents views.

Comment: I think he's asking for how to do this from code.

Comment: And it does not work out-of-the-box in ArcGIS Engine as @Kev84 is stating in his question.

Comment: Mathias is right, this does not work out-of-box for ArcEngine 10, I just double checked. Thanks.